# Java Spring Boot how to know client receive the response from API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I wanna ask. i'm create an API with Java Spring Boot, process then return the response JSON to client, but can i know the client having received the response from the API ?

Example, the client hit the API then API process client request but the client cancel hit process before API finish the job, automatically process on API still running untill finish maybe send the response but the client not receive the response because timout or cancel

any advice ?

Comment: Can you please change your question, probably add bullet points. It is confusing as everything is in single paragraph.

Comment: Is it really relevant? The client did some request to your API and it answered accordingly. What is done with the result, should not be business of your business logic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Once the API receives request and the client terminates the connection or cancel the request, before the response is successfully sent to client, you will see an exception at API end mentioning that the client have aborted the connection.

Comment: i have try with this, but not give exception

Comment: enable debug level logging in your application..you will see the exception "java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer". Also, incase you want to catch this exception then you need to intercept the spring request handler.